# How do I revert back to my old branch name?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have changed the branch name locally ,from (hospital-flow-bug-fix) to (constant-OTP-removal)

Now after using
**git reflog**
I am not able to get the branch from where I cut this(hospital-flow-bug-fix) branch.

I want to know from where I cut the branch named(hospital-flow-bug-fix)

I want to know whether I cut this from Prod branch or Dev branch.

Any command to revert the new branch name ?

Answer (score 0):

If you had pushed that branch `hospital-flow-bug-fix` before, you would still have `origin/hospital-flow-bug-fix` as a marker of the old branch.
But if you had not, and [more than 90 days](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog#Documentation/git-reflog.txt---expirelttimegt) have lapsed since this rename, then `git reflog` woud not help you indeed.

If you have only added commits to `constant-OTP-removal` since the rename (meaning no rebase operation), then you have follow its history until you see de `Dev` or `Prod` branch.

Do a visual check with

```
git log --graph --format=format:"%h% - %aD (%ar)%d%n %s - %an" --abbrev-commit --all --branches
```